# Как вырезать часть текста регулярным выражением в PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

В переменой $a есть текст, необходимо из всего текста вырезать номер телефона (вот регулярка /89\d{9}/) и вставить его в переменную $b. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: опубликуйте пример исходной строки. Номер в строке может встречаться только один раз?

Comment: Пример: 10 метров светящегося в темноте пластика и набор трафаретов в Подарок.
В комплект с 3D ручкой входит пробный набор пластика, но для создания самостоятельных игрушек или композиций его недостаточно. Для простой фигурки понадобится от 10 метров пластика, а для более сложных фигур может понадобится до 100 метров. тел89999999999

Comment: Да номер встречается только один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если номер встречается только один раз, то можно обойтись функцией `preg_replace()`. Составить шаблон таким образом, чтобы он соответствовал всей строке, а его подмаска ссылалась на число из 11 цифр, начинающееся с 89:

```
$str = 'Пример: 10 метров светящегося в темноте пластика и набор трафаретов в Подарок. В комплект с 3D ручкой входит пробный набор пластика, но для создания самостоятельных игрушек или композиций его недостаточно. Для простой фигурки понадобится от 10 метров пластика, а для более сложных фигур может понадобится до 100 метров. тел89999999999';

echo preg_replace('~.*(\b89\d{9}\b).*~', '$1', $str);
```

Результат:

```
89999999999
```

---

**UPD** Можно иначе решить этот пример - с помощью `preg_match()`. В этом случае искать совпадения нужно только по номеру, и соответственно ссылки на подмаски тут не обязательны:

```
$str = 'Пример: 10 метров светящегося в темноте пластика и набор трафаретов в Подарок. В комплект с 3D ручкой входит пробный набор пластика, но для создания самостоятельных игрушек или композиций его недостаточно. Для простой фигурки понадобится от 10 метров пластика, а для более сложных фигур может понадобится до 100 метров. тел89999999999';

preg_match('~\b89\d{9}\b~', $str, $arr);
$number = $arr[0] ?? false;

echo $number;
```

Comment: Live: https://repl.it/repls/GloriousSoupyPasswords

Comment: @Other [смотреть пример на php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a94246281a062db91237e6230622cb63edc63fae) __UPD:__ [смотреть пример на regex](https://regex101.com/r/4aiX0f/1)

Comment: Я знаю что работает, просто решил дать пощупать результат в online-площадках.

Comment: @Other у меня и на вашей площадке работает этот [пример](http://screenshot.ru/upload/images/2018/02/28/151d7e.png)

Comment: Разве я спорил? Просто Вы сразу не дали live, вот я и подкинул пример. Хотите - берите, не хотите - Ваше право :)